# How do I tell which actual dll is being returned (x86 v x64)?

Tags: python, windows, dll, x86, 64-bit

Let's focus on one dll: C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmiutils.dll. Why? Because it's the file in which I personally discovered Windows delivers a different dll depending on process architecture.

TLDR; Is there a way to programmatically determine the actual path of the dll that was returned by the file system redirector?

I understand that if launched as a x86 process, I get C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\wmiutils.dll. And, if launched as a x64 process, I get C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmiutils.dll.

I need to determine which wmiutils.dll I'm actually looking at. The redirector makes system32\wbem\wmiutils.dll look and feel identical but it's not. If I use parent path, I get C:\Windows\System32\wbem even though I may/may not be looking at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem.

Any sweet python magic to make this happen? I can't seem to see anything from other languages I can port. Based on my use case, I've come up with a couple hacks but they're just that. Hoping somebody has found a solution as easy as parent path that actually works in this case.

Comment: Do you need to know which library a running process is using? Or what do you need to know?

Comment: I'm calling files on disk as seen by the os module in python. Not looking for any particular process use of a library or anything. I want to do a SHA1 checksum from C:\\windows\\system32\\wbem\\wmiutil.dll. It is different when python is launched as x86 v x64 because the actual file being returned by the OS isn't the same file. I want to know what the actual file the OS is returning. File system redirector seems to get in the way of this. Looking for a workaround.

Comment: If you can call Win32 API functions, you can use `GetNativeSystemInfo` to determine whether the OS is 32-bit or 64-bit; if it is 64-bit, then you can use `IsWow64Process` to determine whether your process is 32-bit or 64-bit.  The bitness of a loaded DLL will always be the same as that of the process, and even if you aren't loading the DLL, the file system redirector will give you the one matching your process if you use `system32` as the path.  I'm not sure why you're hashing the file, though; you realize the hash may change whenever updates are installed?

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes, hashlib

k32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
oldValue = ctypes.c_long(0)
k32.Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ctypes.byref(oldValue)) # Should open 32-bit
with open(r"C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmiutil.dll", "rb") as f:
    checksum32 = hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest() 

k32.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(oldValue) # Should use what Windows thinks you need
with open(r"C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmiutil.dll", "rb") as f:
    checksum64 = hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest() 

if (checksum32 != checksum64):
    print("You're running 64bit wmiutil dll")
```

I don't have Windows Python to test this, but it should work according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

I think an easier way would be to just do some test like creating a struct and seeing if it's 8 bytes or 4 bytes. Then you can assume that Windows is using the 64-bit version of DLLs if it's 8 bytes.

Comment: The DLL name is plural "wmiutils.dll". If the checksums are different, then it's a WOW64 32-bit process. "System32" is never redirected for a 64-bit process. Your first checksum variable should be named `checksum64`. The second checksum variable should be named `checksum`, and if it's not equal to `checksum64`, then assign it to `checksum32`.

Comment: The straight-forward approach for Python 3 is to use `isredirected = "SysWOW64" in pathlib.Path(r"C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmiutils.dll").resolve().parts`.

Comment: @eryksun I just copy/pasted the path that the OP listed. I actually think my approach would be better by just changing the `open`s to `ctypes.WinDLL("wmiutils.dll")`. I believe WinDLL looks in firstly in cwd and then system32, or it might be `ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(libname)`.

Comment: Why load `wmiutils.dll`? Disabling WOW64 redirection doesn't affect the loader in a WOW64 process; it will still load from SysWOW64, but I don't think the OP wants to load the DLL, anyway.

Comment: Also note that in Windows 7+, a 32-bit process can reference the native system directory as "SysNative", e.g. `r"C:\Windows\SysNative\wbem\wmiutils.dll"`. This directory exists virtually in a WOW64 process; it doesn't exist in a native process.

Comment: @eryksun If you feel it's wrong, feel free to edit it. I don't have the time right now to verify. Or submit another solution and I'll delete this one.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` is documented to only modify the current thread; I've also verified this independently. But the answer still needs to be fixed, since disabling redirection lets you access the native 64-bit "System32" to compute `checksum64`, not `checksum32`. Personally, I prefer to use `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` to just check the final path explicitly. `pathlib.Path.resolve` calls this Windows function.